# The cache isn't working on gitlab CI (can't acces to it on another jobs)

Tags: caching, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this problem, as I can't pass node_modules through artifacts because it's too big, I've created a cache for that, so the principle is that the npm build creates the node_modules and writes it to the cache, and then accesses it in another stage to avoid redoing an npm install which is terribly long.

for information, the build.sh script does an npm install build, and push in a non-detailed way, and gitlab-runner instanciated on kubernetes cluster

thank you for ur HELP

```
.setup_environment:
  image: my image
  cache:  # Cache modules in between jobs
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    policy: pull-push
  before_script:
    - ls -a /var/jenkins_home
    - npm config set .............
    - npm config set .............
    - npm config set noproxy ............
    - node -v && npm -v
    - npm config set registry ..............
    - npm set strict-ssl false

build:
  stage: build
  extends: .setup_environment
  script:
    - package_json=$(cat package.json)
    - echo "MODULE_NAME=$(echo ${CI_PROJECT_NAME} | rev | cut -d- -f2- | rev)" >> build.env
    - echo "MODULE_TIER=$(echo ${CI_PROJECT_NAME} | awk -F- '{print $NF}')" >> build.env
    - echo "MODULE_VERSION=$(echo "$package_json" | jq -r '.version')" >> build.env
    - cat build.env
    - /bin/bash ./build.sh build
    - ls -a
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - test-reports.xml
      - deploy-dist/
      - build.env
      - tmp-tap-report.txt
      - sass-checkstyle.xml
      - eslint-checkstyle.xml
    reports:
      junit: test-reports.xml
      dotenv: build.env

snapshot:
  stage: snapshot
  extends: .setup_environment
  script:
    - ls -a 
    - /bin/bash ./build.sh archive
  dependencies:
    - build 
  rules:
    - !reference [.build_rules, rules]
```

I'm trying to access node_modules from the snapshot stage but when I do a simple ls or cd node_modules I can't find it.